# How to check whether a package installed or not on Ubuntu using python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, apt

Suppose, I'm building an application where shell commands gonna execute. How to check that the command I'm using is available or not?

Comment: Would it make sense for you to use Ansible python API as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subprocess module to execute shell commands

```py
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode("ascii")
```

[How do I check if a package is installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423355/how-do-i-check-if-a-package-is-installed-on-my-server)